# php - automatic string templating

Tags: php, string, templates

I was wondering if there was a way to have an automatic variable replacement inside a string. I can simulate this right now with `preg_replace` and `strtr` but am not sure if there's a better way. I was thinking of using `eval`, but can't seem to figure out how to do it properly.

`strtr`

```
<?php
    $replacement = array('$test' => "dog");
    $template = 'this is a $test';
    $statement = strtr($template, $replacement);
    echo $statement;
?>
```

`preg_replace`

```
<?php
    $template = 'this is a $test';
    $statement = preg_replace('/\$test/', 'dog', $template);
    echo $statement;
?>
```

`eval` idea

```
<?php
    $template = 'this is a $test';
    $test = 'dog';
    eval('$statement = "$template";');
    echo $statement;
?>
```

Comment: You need to be very, very, very, very careful to validate your string to the highest degree before using `eval()`.  `eval()` may make hacking your site much simpler for clever, naughty people.  It is not against the law to use `eval()` but it is often strenuously discouraged due to vulnerabilities.  I would urge you to make `eval()` your plan Z -- only to be used when everything else fails to perform as you require.

Comment: Are the other two functions failing you in any specific situations?  They seem like a wiser choice for this task.

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm thinking it's going to be faster, not sure. `eval` should be safe since they'll be variables I'm defining myself. Not user/client side input.

Comment: Is speed a valid concern for your project? or are you micro-optimizing?

Comment: @mickmackusa ah, not speed as in optimising, speed as in I have to type less. Idk, haven't really thought it out too much lol. I forget the syntax of preg_replace and what not often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[eval()](http://php.net/eval) is to evalute a string as if it's PHP code. So if you did:

```
<?php

$template = 'this is a $test';
$test = 'dog';

eval($template);
echo $template;

?>
```

You would get a syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING)

Because you would in fact do this:

```
<?php

$template = 'this is a $test';
$test = 'dog';

this is a $test;

echo $template;

?>
```

So instead, you need to evaluate it as a string in double quotes so the variable gets replaced by its value:

```
<?php

$template = 'this is a $test';
$test = 'dog';

eval("\$template = \"$template\";");

echo $template;

?>
```

Which would be something like this:

```
<?php

$template = 'this is a $test';
$test = 'dog';

$template = "this is a $test";

echo $template;

?>
```